# How do i find the equation of the tangent line?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the function of the tangent line to $$f(\theta)=5\left(\cos(\pi/3)\cdot\sin(\theta)\right)$$ at $\theta=2\pi/3$

Please show steps and explain. I need to understand this for an upcoming exam.

Comment: The slope is $f'(2\pi/3)$. So the function of the tangent line is of the form $g(\theta)=f'(2\pi/3)\theta+b$. Then plug the point $(2\pi/3,f(2\pi/3))$ to find $b$.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(\theta)=5[\cos(\pi/3)*\sin(\theta)]$$

We want to find $y = mx + b$

$$m = f'(\theta)=\frac{5}{2} Cos(\theta) = -\frac{5}{4} ~\text{when}~ \theta = (2\pi)/3$$

$$b = f(2\pi/3) = \frac{5 \sqrt{3}}{4}$$

So, we get

$$y = -\frac{5}{4} x + \frac{5 \sqrt{3}}{4}$$

Comment: Short and sweet! And "spot on"! +1 (forgot to click on the arrow!!) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Compute the derivative of $f(\theta) = 5[\cos(\pi/3)\sin \theta]$, using, say, the product rule.

Then evaluate $f'$ at $\theta = 2 \pi/3$. Then $f'(2\pi/3) = m$ where $\;m = $ the slope of the line tangent to $f(\theta)$.

Use the fact point-slope form of an equation to determine the precise equation of the line:

$$y - y_0 = m(x - x_0)$$

where $(x_0, y_0)$ is a point known to be on the line.

The point we know is on the line is $\left(2\pi/3, f(2\pi/3)\right)$, so $x_0 = 2\pi/3,\;\;y_0 = f(2\pi/3)$

So the equation of your line will look like this: $$y - f(2\pi/3) = m[x - f(2\pi/3)] = y - f(2\pi/3) = f'(2\pi/3)(x - f(2\pi/3))$$

where $f(2\pi/3)$ is the value of your original equation $f(\theta)$ evaluated at $\theta = 2\pi/3$,

and $f'(2 \pi/3)$ is the value of the derivative of $f(\theta)$ evaluated at $\theta = 2\pi/3$.